# Is android phone are upgradable to new vaesion platform

Tags: android

Recently android have launch 2.1 version, so i just want to ask, can phone running on 1.6 version are upgradable to 2.1 version.

Comment: By upgradeable, do you mean "can I hack the phone, compile 2.1 from sources, or use Cyanogen?" Or do you mean "will my mobile carrier spend X million dollars preparing an offical, validated, debugged ROM as an over-the air update?" The two questions have very different answers.

Comment: I mean will the phone support whatever the version of android launch inn future either by hack or by equipment vendor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason why not. It just depends if the ROM is made available for the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are preparing an app for normal users, they depend on the phone producer - if he will give out new version they might install it, if not, they will stuck with the old version...

Here: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html you can check, which version is most popular. If you want to reach many users, 1.6 should be your choice probably.

Comment: ya i am making an application & i had already read the page you refer to me, even if my application is upgradable to upcoming versions. Customer has to depend on producer of mobile for latest android version support. Am i right?

Comment: yes, you're right. For example G1 phones are now on 1.6 version and there is no sure these will ever get an upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the phone manufacturer on how they want to push the updates to a particular device. for example HTC G1 device has not been updated to ver2.1 due to old hardware while HTC Hero was not updated above ver1.5 due to the incompatibilities of their Sense UI.